# Debugging Android NDK, under windows

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am porting a complex C application to Android, as an SO library, wrapped with thin java layer.
After few hours of hassle, i have the code compiling under Android, but of course, the application crashes :(

After looking around, i understand the only way to debug C application under Android is by gdb. Since I don't have a lot of experience with gdb, any one out there can share some insights?

Anyone has a tutorial for gdb under windows :) ?

thx

Comment: nice, but i can't access it :(

Comment: @ognian your account with the link is suspended...lol I would like t know the answer to this question too as I followed the asnwers link and found that the solution didn't work either.

Answer (score 8):

for a more recent version of NDK (I am using r7c), you can build debug version by

1. add `android:debuggable="true"` flag to `<Application>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. invoke `ndk-build` with `NDK_DEBUG=1` (NDK_DEBUG flag not necessary if running ndk-build with unix shell)

on Windows, things get a bit tricky because to use `ndk-gdb`, you still need bash (or cygwin) as of NDK r7c, yet `ndk-build` running in cygwin bash will run into permission problem if you ever use any of the pre-built static library

my solution on windows machine is

1. add `android:debuggable="true"` flag to `<application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` (same as above)
2. in cmd (windows' command prompt): invoke `ndk-build` with `NDK_DEBUG=1`
3. in cygwin bash: run `ndk-gdb`

for quick initial investigation of native so library, create a simple activity with one button to trigger library entry function and `loadLibrary` in the activity like:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    static {
       System.loadLibrary("mylibrary");
    }

    /* other functions like onCreate, etc... */

    public native void libfunc();

    public void onClick(View v){
       libfunc();
    }
}
```

So when `gdb` starts, the library in question is actually loaded, yet you can still have time to set break points, etc before the program crashes; when you finish setting up the debugger, at `(gdb)` prompt, type `continue` (or just '`c`'), then hit the button to start the crashing program and happy debugging...