# How are you debugging C++ for Android NDK?

Tags: c++, debugging, android-ndk

What are the options for debugging native code on Android? Is gdb the only debugger available? Is their a Visual Studio integration?

I've looked through the Android docs and done the googlesing but am not confident I found the right answer. Hopefully some SO pro's will save me the pain of trial and error.

But if my choices are gdb or printf's, I'll move to Mono for Android instead!

**Solution! [WinGDB](http://www.wingdb.com/wgMobileEdition.htm) is available for Android. Debugging with Visual Studio!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but this [blog post](http://ian-ni-lewis.blogspot.com/2011/01/its-like-coming-home-again.html) explains how to get NDK debugging working in Visual Studio.

Also, I've done a lot of looking into NDK debugging at work, and I haven't seen a mention of using a debugger other than gdb (but please don't take this as a fact, this is just from my experience). I have managed to successfully debug NDK through Eclipse, so at least you know it's possible! If you decide to go down that route, I can provide you with some links/documentation to get you started.

---

**Edit:** I have *finally* found the time to format and upload my NDK debugging documentation. It's not amazing right now (in terms of formatting etc.), but it has worked for a few people across all platforms. You can find it [here](http://esotericgamer.co.uk/pro/android-ndk.html). I hope it helps!

Comment: +1 but can you post the links/documentation you mentioned for the benefit of others reading this post please :)

Comment: Sorry for replying so late - I've been very busy. Yes, sure, I'll post stuff here over the weekend :)

Comment: @Merlin I don't know if you get notified of my edit, so I'm commenting here to let you know I've linked to the guide. Sorry it took so long, and I hope it helps.

Comment: the link ( You can find it "here")  is dead

Answer (score 0):

I found these macro defs but beyond that I cannot say.

```
#include <android/log.h>

#define LOGV(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "libnav",
__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG  , "libnav",
__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO   , "libnav",
__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGW(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN   , "libnav",
__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR  , "libnav",
__VA_ARGS__)

#endif // ANDROID_ALOG_H
```

*UPDATE*

Apparently you can use DDD either as a plugin to eclipse as found on [Code Maemo](http://codemaemo.appforce.org/2010/07/debugging-native-android-code-with-ddd/)

or run under Cygwin, you will find some useful links in [Debugging Android NDK, under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3238408/808940)

Additionally there are some very useful plugins

[CDT plugin for eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php)

[Sequoya plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/downloads/index.php)

The installation and configuration of the stack is detailed in [How-to debug native code with Android](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2010/12/14/how-to-debug-native-code-with-android/)

Comment: I'm after a definitive answer on whether gdb is the only debugger for native code. Sorry my original post was not very clear. Thanks Merlin.

Comment: I have provided additional information but it l ooks like everything centres around gdb

Comment: My understanding is that gdb is the supported debugger.  But the tutorials I have found all seem either out of date or just plain wrong.  I have yet to see a tutorial that works with NDK r5b and the current Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

For further reference, I like this solution that shows how to use graphical derivatives of gdb, such as cgdb (http://cgdb.github.com/) and ddd (http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/): http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-cgdb-with-ndk-debug-and-cgdb-tutorial/