# ndk-gdb on windows

Tags: android-ndk, gdb

i m trying to debug my jni section of application by running ngk-gdb on windows machine with android-ndk-r8b.
i am using cygwin and c/c++ plugin for eclipse.my device is galaxy s, android 2.3.7

what i did is followed the instructions on [Using Eclipse for Android C/C++ Debugging](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/),
but i am stuck on running ndk-gdb, getting this error:

```
Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi
ERROR: The device does not support the application's targetted CPU ABIs!
       Device supports:  armeabi-v7a armeabi
       Package supports:
```

thx for your help

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the problem recently and in my case it was a cygwin issue.  make was not installed in cygwin and this created problems further along in the ndk-gdb script.  After installing make using the cygwin setup.exe (select make under Devel - on another recommendation, I also installed tcsh under Shells), the "ABIS targetted by application:" line shows the app's targeted ABI.

Without make:

```
/cygdrive/c/work/android/android-ndk-r8b-windows/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-gdb: line 105: make: command not found  
ABIs targetted by application:  
Device API Level: 15  
Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi  
ERROR: The device does not support the application's targetted CPU ABIs!  
       Device supports:  armeabi-v7a armeabi  
       Package supports:
```

With make properly installed:

```
ABIs targetted by application: armeabi-v7a  
Device API Level: 15  
Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi  
Compatible device ABI: armeabi-v7a
```

Application.mk, located in the jni folder, can be used to specify the app's targeted ABI - an example:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_OPTIM := debug
```

Good luck!

Comment: This worked for me. After I reinstalled Cygwin-64bit, I forgot to install 'make' packages. Thanks.

Comment: The tricky part here is that to run `ndk-build`, you do not need `cygwin`; worse - you should use `ndk\prebuilt\windows\bin\make` and never  `cygwin\bin\make`! But to run `ndk-gdb`, you need cygwin and its `make`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238408/debugging-android-ndk-under-windows

Answer (score 0):

For all others like me with Nexus (devices) updated with Android 4.3 there are bugs that hinder Native code debugging. (I tried everything found on SO :)

> 1. Either root your device and try
> 2. Or Update nexus 4.3 factory image [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) (and this is reported working by google android dev)
> 3. Or wait for Android 4.4 update to come to your device (as bug is identified and fix in the source tree by Google by not yet packaged
>      released)

Comment: I confirm that with android 4.4 native debugging is working with eclipse adt on windows