# Geting started with Android C++ debugging via gdb on Windows: Where to get gdbserver for Android from?

Tags: windows, debugging, command-line, android-ndk, usb-debugging

I don't understand how to debug C++ APKs on android. Can someone please help me get started?

I found this:
http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/debugging_gdb.html

but running `gdbserver -help` from the terminal emulator on the actual device returns "gdbserver: not found". Everything I've found online says to run gdbserver on the device, but I don't know how to get it. Or what to do from there.

Please note I am running Windows for the `adb` connection, but the ndk build system is in a Linux virtual machine via terminal. `gdb-ndk` must be run directly from Windows for this Android device to communicate via usb. `adb logcat` only finds the device under Windows.

Thanks

I've also seen these links:

1. [ndk-gdb on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020245/ndk-gdb-on-windows)
2. http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/
3. http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/how-cc-debugging-works-on-android/
4. http://cgdb.github.io/
5. http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-cgdb-with-ndk-debug-and-cgdb-tutorial/
6. http://geekswithblogs.net/raccoon_tim/archive/2011/09/12/working-with-android-on-windows-and-without-cygwin.aspx
7. http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/documentation/native_debug.php

Comment: Update, I have gdbserver located in /data/local but I can seem to run it as superuser, as it says `# ./gdbserver : permission denied`

Comment: changed permissions using `chmod 770 ./gdbserver` after realizing it was missing the +x when I checked with `ls -l ./gdbserver`

Comment: Still confused about how to get the communication channel for gdbserver to gdbclient working though