# Android NDK and cygwin : incorrect path?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, cygwin

I have the following in my ".bashrc"

```
export ANDROID_SDK=/cygdrive/c/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/sdk
export ANDROID_NDK=/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8d
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_NDK
```

When I build the project it fails with the error below.

```
Android NDK: No local settings... build all in release mode !
Android NDK: ERROR:/home/XXX/jni/Android.mk:gcc: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that //c:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/libgcc.a exists  or that its path is correct
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:43: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

Using the shell I can see that

> **//c:/** android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/libgcc.a"

cannot be found, yet

> **/cygdrive/c/** android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/libgcc.a

can be found. So the question is why is the NDK expanding the drive/path like this? (you can see it does not always do this see the last line of the error)

Is there a fix?

Comment: Are you building from bash or from Eclipse/CDT?

Comment: From bash - I also get the same error from a windows prompt using the command : "\android-ndk-r8d\ndk-build.cmd"

Comment: For a long while, **ndk-build** does not work with **cygwin**. But you still [need cygwin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10307638/192373) for **ndk-gdb**!